# Need 1 MVC controller for 2 functions (create entity & upload img), which are separated

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, model-view-controller, controller

I spent 2 days to find solution of my problem, but didn't get any result. If you can give me a link with good example - please post it, because I didn't find any... If you need some more info about my problem - please ask me for more details! So, the problem is: I have 2 controllers(first for creating entity, second for uploading img for this entity). Now I need to create one entity with possibility to upload img for this entity with only one controller.
So, the code of controller for entity creating is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAddGroup(Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("group") @Valid final Group group,
            final BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            HttpSession httpSession) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(
                    "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.group",
                    result);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("group", group);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("groupNotCreated", true);
            return "redirect:/groups";
        }
        groupService.create(group);
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", group.getId()).addFlashAttribute(
                "groupCreated", true);
        return GROUP_LINK;
    }
```

The code of controller for img uploading is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add-group-img", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addGroupPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] file,
            @ModelAttribute("group") final Group group,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id", group.getId());
        imageService.addImageToGroup(file, group);
        return GROUP_LINK;
    }
```

Now all works fine, but I need to give user opportunity to create group with img at the same time, but not by different actions. When I tried to to set `MultipartFile` into entity-creating controller it not works. Please, explain me how **can I resolve it with changing only controller**, is it possible?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: So you want an HTML form where user can submit group info, along with a file input field where they can attach an image to the group, yes? And it all happens in one POST.

Comment: Yes, in one POST. But in modal window, not HTML form.